# Convert Pyspark dataframe to dictionary

Tags: dictionary, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a Pyspark dataframe into a dictionary.

Here's the sample CSV file -

```
Col0, Col1
-----------
A153534,BDBM40705
R440060,BDBM31728
P440245,BDBM50445050
```

I've come up with this code -

```
from rdkit import Chem
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read.csv("gs://my-bucket/my_file.csv") # has two columns

# Creating list
to_list = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())

#Creating dictionary
to_dict = {x['col0']: x for x in to_list }
```

This creates a dictionary like below -

```
'A153534': {'col0': 'A153534', 'col1': 'BDBM40705'}, 'R440060': {'col0': 'R440060', 'col1': 'BDBM31728'}, 'P440245': {'col0': 'P440245', 'col1': 'BDBM50445050'}
```

But I want a dictionary like this -

`{'A153534': 'BDBM40705'}, {'R440060': 'BDBM31728'}, {'P440245': 'BDBM50445050'}`

How can I do that?

I tried the *rdd* solution by Yolo but I'm getting error. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
>   o80.isBarrier. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does
>   not exist
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I think you want `{x['col0']: x['col1'] for x in to_list }`

Comment: I have provided the dataframe version in the answers. Try if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it using [`rdd`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html):

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: {x.Col0: x.Col1}).collect()

[{'A153534': 'BDBM40705'}, {'R440060': 'BDBM31728'}, {'P440245': 'BDBM50445050'}]
```

Comment: Hi Yolo, I'm getting an error. I've shared the error in my original question. Can you help me with that?

Comment: can you show the schema of your dataframe? also your pyspark version

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:

```py
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/Create_dict.txt',header=True)

df = df.withColumn('dict',to_json(create_map(df.Col0,df.Col1)))

df_list = [row['dict'] for row in df.select('dict').collect()]

df_list
```

Output is:

```py
['{"A153534":"BDBM40705"}',
 '{"R440060":"BDBM31728"}',
 '{"P440245":"BDBM50445050"}']
```